# Galeria de Vídeos do Youtube em PHP e/ou Javascript

Tags: galeria, youtube-api

Eu tinha uma galeria de vídeos do Youtube que aparecia na tela o último vídeo de um canal, em tamanho normal e depois aparecia logo abaixo mais 50 vídeos em miniatura, sendo que quando era clicado em uma dessas miniaturas, o vídeo era aberto no lugar daquele que tinha o tamanho maior, até aí tudo certo!

Mas com a mudança da API v2 para v3, não aparece mais os vídeos e sim um vídeos do youtube com uma mensagem do suporte. Já visitei a página desse suporte mas não consegui resolver.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso ou tem um código que atenda essa situação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi em partes essa situação, não entendo muito do assunto, mas vi um vídeo em Inglês e consegui tirar um bom proveito sobre o assunto.

Primeiro você entra no endereço: *www.console.developers.google.com/project/507871535838/apiui/credential* , faz o login e gera uma Chave para aplicativos do navegador, parecida com essa: `AIzaSyAUdzBYnsoHcgeDqY9sflH0bv0XaIBjpsI` você vai utiliza-la no `script.js`

Depois você baixa o arquivo `jquery-1.11.3.min.js` e cria 2 arquivos: `index.html` e `script.js`

No `index.html` que você criou, chama os arquivos `.js` e para mostrar os vídeos, você chama através do código abaixo no body do *index*.

```
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

Agora crie o `script.js`:

```
var channelName = 'Aqui vai o nome do canal';
var vidWidth = 250; //largura de cada vídeos
var vidHeight = 187; //altura de cada vídeos
var vidResults = 10; //qtd de vídeos que vai aparecer na galeria max 50

$(document).ready(function(){
$.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",{
        part: 'contentDetails',
        forUsername: channelName,
        key: 'AIzaSyAUdzBYnsoHcgeDqY9sflH0bv0XaIBjpsI'},//altere para sua chave
        function(data){
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                console.log(item);
                pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
                getVids(pid);
            })
        }
);

function getVids(pid){
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
            part: 'snippet',
            maxResults: vidResults,
            playlistId: pid,
            key: 'AIzaSyAUdzBYnsoHcgeDqY9sflH0bv0XaIBjpsI'},//altere para sua chave
            function(data){
                var output;
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                    console.log(item);
                    videTitle = item.snippet.title;
                    videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                    output = '<li><iframe width="'+vidWidth+'" height="'+vidHeight+'" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId+'\"></iframe></li>';
                    //Append to resultes listStyleType
                    $('#results').append(output);
                })
            }
    );    
}
});
```

Espero ter ajudado, como disse: sou leigo, mas se alguém quiser melhorar, fique a vontade.